# CFA - How do within-factor error covariances affect how a psychometric scale is used/scored?

Tags: factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor, psychometrics

I'm working on a confirmatory factor analysis for a measure with one factor, 8 items, each is a 7-point Likert scale. Two items within the factor are worded very similarly and their errors are likely correlated for that reason. The items do have different meanings, and there isn't strong justification for removing one or the other.
I would like to model this error covariance, but I do not understand the implications for the future use of this measure. Currently (based on a previous EFA), it is scored as an individual's average score (i.e., sum all scores, divide by number of items). How would modifying the measure to include the error covariance affect how it is scored/interpreted?